Cannot start Selenium node because this.node is null
I am trying to start the Selenium server node on Oracle Linux 8.9.
Starting the hub works fine.
When I try to start the node, I get the error:
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.getStatus()" because "this.node" is null

Please note that the web drivers are in the path.
Selenium server is version 4.21.0.
Here is a more thorough stack trace.
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.ClassCreation.callCreateMethod(ClassCreation.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.lambda$getClass$4(MemoizedConfig.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.getClass(MemoizedConfig.java:99)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.ConfigException: No drivers have been configured or have been found on PATH
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.addDetectedDrivers(NodeOptions.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.NodeOptions.getSessionFactories(NodeOptions.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNodeFactory.create(LocalNodeFactory.java:79)
    ... 22 more
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.getStatus()" because "this.node" is null
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.lambda$new$0(NodeServer.java:78)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Here is the command:
java -jar ./software/selenium/server/selenium-server-4.21.0.jar node --port 5555 --selenium-manager true --max-sessions 1 

